# Hot reload of certificates in istio (version 1.15.1) sidecar proxy

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar

I have a simple HTTP server POD into which I have injected the istio proxy using the annotation:
sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"

PeerAuthentication used is STRICT and so the TLS connections are terminated at the injected proxy. The certificates are mounted into the sidecar at folder /etc/certs from a secret named 'istio.default'.

Every thing works fine until here. But when the secret 'istio.default' is updated (as a result of the certificate update) the proxy does not use the new certificate at all. I confirmed this by using 'openssl s_client -connect test-service.default.svc.cluster.local:80 -showcerts' command from within another POD (that does not have the istio proxy injected) in the same cluster.

When the secret changes, I do see the following logs in the istio-proxy sidecar container:

```
2023-10-06T16:30:01.052826Z     info    cache   event for file certificate /etc/certs/cert-chain.pem : REMOVE, pushing to proxy
2023-10-06T16:30:01.052929Z     info    ads     XDS: Incremental Pushing:0 ConnectedEndpoints:4 Version:
2023-10-06T16:30:01.053103Z     info    cache   event for file certificate /etc/certs/root-cert.pem : REMOVE, pushing to proxy
2023-10-06T16:30:01.053127Z     info    ads     XDS: Incremental Pushing:0 ConnectedEndpoints:4 Version:
2023-10-06T16:30:01.053443Z     info    cache   adding watcher for file certificate /etc/certs/root-cert.pem
2023-10-06T16:30:01.053477Z     info    cache   read certificate from file      resource=file-root:/etc/certs/root-cert.pem
2023-10-06T16:30:01.053614Z     info    cache   adding watcher for file certificate /etc/certs/cert-chain.pem
2023-10-06T16:30:01.053641Z     info    cache   read certificate from file      resource=file-cert:/etc/certs/cert-chain.pem~/etc/certs/key.pem
```

'istioctl pc secret' command output (after the secret is updated) is as follows:

```
RESOURCE NAME                                              TYPE           STATUS     VALID CERT     SERIAL NUMBER                                        NOT AFTER                NOT BEFORE
default                                                    Cert Chain     ACTIVE     true           451472921626080590577053505835972260216906524344     2024-10-05T16:19:30Z     2023-10-06T16:19:31Z
file-cert:/etc/certs/cert-chain.pem~/etc/certs/key.pem     Cert Chain     ACTIVE     true           632858167013452885213865893556489742682005531802     2024-10-05T20:01:05Z     2023-10-06T20:01:06Z
file-root:/etc/certs/root-cert.pem                         CA             ACTIVE     true           37522736071096118890366314454134530923901408613      2033-08-06T19:44:21Z     2023-08-09T19:44:22Z
ROOTCA                                                     CA             ACTIVE     true           37522736071096118890366314454134530923901408613      2033-08-06T19:44:21Z     2023-08-09T19:44:22Z
```

Before the update, the first 2 entries have the same serial number.

Is there any additional configuration required to get hot reload of certificates to work ?